# Schedule a SQL Job to send an email alerts if Column is NULL in SQL 2016?

Tags: jobs, sql-server-2016, sql-server-agent

How to schedule a job in SQL server, when SQL Job to send an email alert if Column 'Volume' in Table 'table1' is NULL?

Comment: Have you configured a working [Database Mail Profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/database-mail/create-a-database-mail-profile) yet?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have set up a working [Database Mail Profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/database-mail/create-a-database-mail-profile), you can create a scheduled [SQL Agent Job](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439(v=sql.110).aspx) that on a suitable schedule executes [`sp_send_dbmail`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql) with your specific parameters as required.

For Example:

```
declare @NullCheck nvarchar(100);
set @NullCheck = (select YourColumn from YouTable);

if @NullCheck is null
execute msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'YourDBMailProfileName'
                               ,@recipients = 'YourEmail@Example.com'
                               ,@subject = 'Column is NULL'
                               ,@body = 'The Column is currently NULL'
```